# Unable to remove surface mount light fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I have a Satco CFL Ceiling light fixture which was installed when we purchased our condo. The fixture had a twist and screw style dome which got broken and I am unable to find a replacement, so I was going to replace the whole fixture.

I see two screws in the middle, and I had assumed that when I would unscrew them the fixture would come off. But even after unscrewing them it's just stuck really tight on the ceiling and it doesn't seem to budge.

I have tried twisting the fixture. I tried browsing the Satco product page but I wasn't able to find this model anywhere.

I was hoping that someone here may be able to shed some light on how I can remove the fixture.

I would also be happy to just get a replacement dome, but don't know where to look.

[image: Light Fixture].

Comment: +1 "*shed some light*" -  Perhaps,  "throw some shade"

Comment: I've seen replacement glass shades at homedepot.  They may not be the right brand but I have a feeling that a lot of those shades are interchangeable so you might be able to use one as long as the size is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would bet that it is being held on by paint.
The two screws should be the only mechanical fasteners.

Take a utility knife and cut the paint line between the ceiling and the metal of the fixture and then use a thin scraper to push in between the ceiling and the metal of the fixture to pop it free.

If you have a Habitat for Humanity Restore or a home salvage store  you can go and look through their used fixtures

Answer (score 2):

It looks like part of that insulation is factory-cut, so it can fold back like a flap.  I would pull that out gently (or ungently if you are scrapping this fixture) and see what's behind it.  I bet you find the mounting screws.